# datanucleus-jodatime : failed to add record in google appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, jodatime, datanucleus

I am using JPA (requirement so didn't use Low level API or Objectify) with Google app engine. It works well with Java util date but not with Jodatime and I'm getting this error message:

```
[INFO] 14:29:08,836 ERROR 947474820@qtp-410885064-0 Persistence:error:115 - User-defined type mapping class "org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.mapping.JodaDateTimeMapping" was not found. Please check the mapping file class specifications and your CLASSPATH. The class must be in the CLASSPATH.

[INFO] 14:29:08,841 ERROR 947474820@qtp-410885064-0 Persistence:error:115 - User-defined type mapping class "org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.mapping.JodaLocalDateMapping" was not found. Please check the mapping file class specifications and your CLASSPATH. The class must be in the CLASSPATH.

[INFO] 14:29:08,847 ERROR 947474820@qtp-410885064-0 Persistence:error:115 - User-defined type mapping class "org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.mapping.JodaLocalTimeMapping" was not found. Please check the mapping file class specifications and your CLASSPATH. The class must be in the CLASSPATH.

[INFO] 14:29:08,852 ERROR 947474820@qtp-410885064-0 Persistence:error:115 - User-defined type mapping class "org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.mapping.JodaDurationMapping" was not found. Please check the mapping file class specifications and your CLASSPATH. The class must be in the CLASSPATH.

[INFO] 14:29:08,858 ERROR 947474820@qtp-410885064-0 Persistence:error:115 - User-defined type mapping class "org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.mapping.JodaIntervalMapping" was not found. Please check the mapping file class specifications and your CLASSPATH. The class must be in the CLASSPATH.

[INFO] 14:29:08,862 ERROR 947474820@qtp-410885064-0 Persistence:error:115 - User-defined type mapping class "org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.mapping.JodaPeriodMapping" was not found. Please check the mapping file class specifications and your CLASSPATH. The class must be in the CLASSPATH.
```

Answer (score 0):

So you didn't put the datanucleus-jodatime jar in your CLASSPATH.
Pick the version appropriate to your version of GAE

Comment: I did add datanucleus-jodatime dependency. What I did not add was datanucleus-rdbms dependency. All the error messages are disappeared now.